# Facebook API implementation

Tags: javascript, facebook

Suppose I search people by name on facebook . And I get thousands of results . Now , if I want to  send a message to  each people  from result list automatically . Can it be done using Facebook API or By using java script ?

Comment: My college fire wall blocks any link, search results which includes facebook word . so I had to write that way . sorry for that .

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully, the answer is a resounding **no**. This is simply not possible. As I'm sure you can imagine, a decision was made by Facebook *not to allow* applications to send messages to random people. The spamming vulnerabilities are very real.